# ruby on rails access associated table from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have a method in my **Post model** which gets the **user posts**

```
  def self.find_user_posts(user_id)
    where(:user_id => user_id).limit(15)
  end
```

then in **view** i have

```
<% Post.find_user_posts(@user.id).each do |p| %>
    <%= render_post(p) %>
<% end %>
```

which then **call a partial** called `/posts/_post.html.erb`

my problem is that i want to get each user picture from the **users** table since both tables share a foreign column called **user_id**

i also have in **post model**

```
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'post_id'
```

and in **user model**

```
has_many :post, :foreign_key => 'post_id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this.

in your view

```
<% @user.posts.limit(15).each do |post| %>
  <%= render_post(post) %>
<% end %>
```

This will let you delete

```
def self.find_user_posts(user_id)
    where(:user_id => user_id).limit(15)
end
```

Which should be a named_scope if needed.

Then in your _post partial you should be able to do something like

```
<%= image_tag(post.user.image_url) %>
```

to show each user's image it per post.

Comment: awesome! rails is getting better and better!